# Email not been sent from the finish method of a batch job in a unit test

Tags: apex, unit-test, email, schedulebatch

The below code is to validate if an email has been sent from the finish method of a batch job using the Limits.getEmailInvocations(). The afterEmail variable is been set to 0 and no email is been sent from the test.

```
    @isTest 
    static void sendEmailToScheduledJobUser() {
        Test.startTest();
        Integer beforeEmail = Limits.getEmailInvocations();

        Database.executeBatch(new TestBatch(), 50);

        Integer afterEmail = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
        System.assert(beforeEmail != afterEmail, 'Email not sent to the schedule job user');
        Test.stopTest();
}
```

The finish method of the batch job sends an email.

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) 
{
    sendEmail(context);
}
```

When executing the batch job in the developer console, I do receive the email. For testing purposes, I have hardcoded the email address in the batch job.

Answer (score 3):

The asynchronous code will not run until your test hits `Test.stopTest()`, at which point the limits reset. You cannot test that asynchronous code sends an email. However, if your `sendEmail` method will work with a `null` input, you can call the `finish` method directly.

```
Test.startTest();
    new MyBatch().finish(null);
    Integer emailInvocations = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: Or a static `@TestVisible` variable to verify the code was called, but most people don't like to use that technique.